# JSplitPane Background image on right side component

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, jsplitpane

I have a JSplitPane. i want to add background image to the left side of the JSplitPane.

```
mySplitPane.getLeftComponent
```

this returs the left side component. and then i want to add an image background to the left side. i think i can use the `Paint()`
 to set background image to the JSplitPane. but how can i set on the only left side component.

I have a JTable on left side of my JSplitPane. i want to have JTable transparent. and then showing the background image.

Right now i have set background to my JTable. i dont want the background to be scrolled with JTable Scroll. Thats why i want to add background image to the Split Pane not the Table.

Comment: Try this wonderful answer given here by @AndrewThompson , [How to add JPanel to a JLabel for showing Animated Image as background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141111/1057230)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    public ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.load(...);
JPanel leftPanel = new ImagePanel(myImage);

//Add panel to splitpanel
JSplitPane mySplitPane= new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT)
mySplitPane.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
```

> Above I have created a subclass of JComponent. Override the
>   paintComponent(Graphics g) method to paint the image that I want to
>   display. I then set the content pane of the JPanel and then finally
>   pass the panel to the left of the split pane

For more on Watermark background, see [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d/) for examples and code samples.
Edited

Comment: i have a table on left side component. i want to have table transparent and then showing the background image behind JTable. if i set left component as a image then where to add my table?

Comment: see Edited: `JPanel leftPanel = new ImagePanel(myImage);`

Comment: ImagePanel leftPanel = new ImagePanel(myImage);
leftPanel.add(tblMainView,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
splitPaneMain.setRightComponent(leftPanel); this not showing my Table on Panel.

Comment: See edited: `class ImagePanel extends JPanel` and the new draw args.

Comment: Also see edited for link to more on watermark background and example codes.